# In PHP Stop only "IF" once it true in Foreach loop and Continue Foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach, break

How to stop `IF` conduction in side the loop, once it `TRUE` without stopping loop.
I want to get HTML output as following,

```
<div1>
  Group_1
      Item_1
      Item_21
      Item_43
      Item_55
  Group_2
      Item_5
      Item_34
      Item_56
  Group_3
      Item_12
  Group_4
      Item_11
      Item_14
      Item_15
</div1>

<div2>
  Group_5
      Item_2
      Item_3
  Group_6
      Item_6
      Item_7
      Item_9
  Group_7
      Item_10
      Item_41
      Item_42
      Item_43
  Group_8
      Item_13
</div2>

<div3>
  Group_9
      Item_16
      Item_17
      Item_18
      Item_19
      Item_20
      Item_30
      Item_31
      Item_32
      Item_33
      Item_35
      Item_40
      Item_44
</div3>

<div4>
   Group_10
      Item_4
      Item_22
      Item_23
  Group_11
      Item_24
      Item_25
</div4>
```

My PHP code is as following,

```
<?php
  $x=0;
  $num_g =  count($groups);
  $num_i =  count($items);
  $lines =  $num_g+$num_i;
  $div1 = 13;
  $div2 = 26;
  $div3 = 39;
  $div4 = 51;

  foreach($groups as $group){

    if($x==0){ 
      echo'<div class="div1">'; // Start First DIV
    }
      $x++; 

    echo 'Group - '.$group->name.'<br>'; // Group Name
    foreach($items as $item){
      if($item->group_id == $group->id) //Group Items
          $x++; 
          echo $item->name.'<br>';  // Item Name
      }


    if($x>=$div1){  // Need to stop Only this If once it TRUE ??
        echo '</div><div class="div2">'; // Start 2nd DIV
    }

    if($x>=$div2){   // Need to stop Only this If once it TRUE ??
        echo '</div><div class="div3">'; // Start 3rd DIV
    }

    if($x>=$div3){  // Need to stop Only this If once it TRUE ??
        echo '</div><div class="div4">'; // Start 4th DIV
    }

    if($x==$lines) {   // Need to stop Only this If once it TRUE ??
        echo '</div>'; // End Last DIV
    }
  }
```

Please, Can anyone help or advice about this matter ?

Comment: Have you tried adding any [`breaks;`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)?

Comment: Yes, I Tried,  The loop stopped after the break

Answer (score 1):

Use the `continue` keyword. the official PHp [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) says:

> continue is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

use `continue` statement in the place you want to skip the remain code in the foreach. refer to the [**manual**](http://php.net/manual/zh/control-structures.continue.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code:

```
    if($x==$lines) {   // Need to stop Only this If once it TRUE ??
        echo '</div>'; // End Last DIV
        break;
    }
    if($x>=$div3){  // Need to stop Only this If once it TRUE ??
        echo '</div><div class="div4">'; // Start 4th DIV
        continue;
    }
    if($x>=$div2){   // Need to stop Only this If once it TRUE ??
        echo '</div><div class="div3">'; // Start 3rd DIV
        continue;
    }
    if($x>=$div1){  // Need to stop Only this If once it TRUE ??
        echo '</div><div class="div2">'; // Start 2nd DIV
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment,  main `foreach` loop stopped, After the `break;`